# VBA lookup a range name in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

This should be simple but I cannot get the examples online to solve my error.
Thanks for your help.

Regards Peter

I have 2 sheets:  **BOQ and OrderCodes**

I am looping through rows in BOQ column"B" and when i find a value I lookup a Named Range in OrderCodes sheet

The Range is called "**Lookup_CostCodes**"

An example of the Vlookup i require is
Vlookup(1002,LookupCostCodes,3,false)

The relevant code is as follows:

```
Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim OrderCodesWs As Worksheet
Dim CostCodesRng As Range
Set OrderCodesWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OrderCodes")
Set CostCodesRng = OrderCodesWs.Range("Lookup_CostCodes")

On Error GoTo failure
Set sourceSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("BOQ")
outputRow = START_ROW

Dim sheet As Worksheet

For i = 1 To Range("_7000").row
    If Val(sourceSheet.Cells(i, 11).Value) <> 0 And sourceSheet.Cells(i, 11).HasFormula Then
            orderRef = sourceSheet.Cells(i, 2)
            costCodeValue = Val(sourceSheet.Cells(i, 1))
            costCode = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(costCodeValue, "CostCodes!" & CostCodesRng.Address, 3, False)
    
    End If
Next i
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: For the 2nd argument of the VLookup function just pop in the Lookup_CostCodes range that you've already defined `costCode = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(costCodeValue, CostCodesRng, 3, False)`

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I should have looked more closely at your comment.  It has fixed my problem in combination with braX.

I created a simplified version of my workbook as i couldn't see why the answers were not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote the following snippet to address your problem. If this is what you wanted then please do integrate it in your main code.

```
Public Worksheet As Worksheet
Set Worksheet = Worksheets("BOQ")

Range("B2:B" &amp; lr).Select

For Each cell In Selection


If cell.Value &lt;&gt; "" Then

    cell.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Select

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Lookup_CostCodes!C[-1]:C[0],2,FALSE)"

    Range("B2").Select

End If

Next
```